# Problem on compactness of convergent sequence in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\} \to x$ be a convergent sequence in a metric space. I want to prove that the set $\{x_n\}\cup x$ is compact. I guess it follows easily from the fact that any seqence in $\Bbb R$ has a non-decreasing subsequence. Am I correct ?

Comment: It is an arbitrary metric space.. Why are you considering the case of just $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Use the fact that any open neighborhood of $x$ contains all but finitely many points of $x_n$.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Take any sequence from the set $\{x_n\} \cup x$. It will correspond to shuffling/ repeatation of the original sequence. Consider the indexes of the new sequence. It is a sequence in $\Bbb R$. Hence has a non-decreasing subsequence $n(k)$. But $x_{n(k)}$ converges. Is the proof correct ?

Answer (score 2):

To show that $A=\{x_n\}\cup \{x\}$ is compact;

Let $A=\cup_{\alpha\in I} U_\alpha$ then $x\in U_\alpha $ for some $\alpha \in I$;

since $x_n$ converges $\exists m\in \mathbb N $ such that $x_n\in U_\alpha$ forall $n\geq m$

Thus we are only left with a finite number of terms of the sequence outside $U_\alpha$  for which we require finite number of members of $\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$

Answer (score 1):

Given $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $N$ s.t. $$n> N\Rightarrow
   |x_n -x|<\varepsilon $$

If $y_k$ is a sequence in $M=\{x_n\}\cup \{ x\}$, then if $y_k \in \{ x_n\}_{n=1}^s\cup \{ x\}$ for some $s$,
    then it has a convergent subsequence. If not for any $K$, there exists
    $ n_K$ s.t. $$ n_K > K,\ x_{n_K}=z_K,\ z_K\in \{ y_k\} $$

So clearly $z_K$ is a subsequence in $\{ y_k\}$. Note that $$ K> N
\Rightarrow |x- z_K |  = |x- x_{n_K} | < \varepsilon $$

So $z_K$ converges to $x$. This argument on $({\bf R}, |\cdot|)$ can be applied to general metric space.